# Is there a way to get a list of installed .NET updates without searching the registry?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, updates

Is there a way to get a list of installed .NET updates on Windows Server 2008 R2 without searching the registry? I have found many ways to get them:
 - Manually from Control Panel
 - Search the registry
 - Enable Reliability Records and then use WMI or CIM. (Can't do it in this env)
Many sites show ways to get Windows Updates, and even the versions of .NET that are installed, but not the .NET patches/updates (unless you specify the registry).
I prefer to use PowerShell, but at this point I'll take whatever I can get (except direct query to registry). I'm looking for a native class/function/tool, etc. that can do it.

Here's a verbose (for management) example of how we do it now. It's trimmed down to the bone when we use in our scripts.

```
Function Get-SingleDotNetPatchRegistryData
{
Param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$DotNetKBnumber,
    [string]$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates"
    )

Write-Host "`r`n.NET Patch KB Number: "
Write-Host "    $DotNetKBnumber`r`n"
$DotNetKBsearchString = '*' + $DotNetKBnumber + '*'
$DotNetPatchRegDataHashTable = $null
$DotNetPatchRegDataHashTable = @{}

$DotNetPatchRegKeyProp = `
Get-ChildItem $RegPath -Recurse -Force |
 Where {$_.Name -like $DotNetKBsearchString} | Get-ItemProperty

If ($DotNetPatchRegKeyProp)
    {
    $DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrs = $DotNetPatchRegKeyProp |
     Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

    # Write-Host ".NET Patch Data from Registry:"
    ForEach($DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbr in $DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrs)
        {
        $DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrName = $DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbr.Name
        $RawDotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrValue = `
         $DotNetPatchRegKeyProp.($DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrName)
        $DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrValue = $RawDotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrValue`
         -replace('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\Registry::','')
        $EchoText = "    Field Name: $DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrName`r`n" + `
         "    Field Value: $DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrValue`r`n"
        # Write-Host $EchoText
        $DotNetPatchRegDataHashTable.add("$DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrName",`
         "$DotNetPatchRegKeyPropMbrValue")
        }
        $DotNetPatchRegDataHashTable.add("Installed", $true")
    }
Else
    {
    $DotNetPatchRegDataHashTable.add("Installed", $false)
    }
Return $DotNetPatchRegDataHashTable
}
```

Comment: Unless it's some sort of weird policy that you can't use WMI/CIM, you could do the query from within powershell. `Get-CimInstance Win32_QuickFixEngineering`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You sir toss out some obscure (but amazingly useful) references like Win32_QuickFixEngineering, and the Zip method from the LINQ library yesterday. Where do you find this stuff or is it just things you know off hand from whatever it is you do?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I don't know what it is, I might have some sort of associative memory synesthesia that is highly optimized for remembering Microsoft product trivia :P

Comment: Nope. Just tried Get-CimInstance Win32_QuickFixEngineering. It lists lots of patches, but it will not list any .NET patches. Are you saying this does work for you? If so, have you enabled reliability records on that server?

Comment: I have to move on with this, so I will specify the registry locations for now, but the boss does not like that. He will just have to get over it unless he can come up with something better. Thanks all.

Comment: @JCSunday No, you're right, the `QuickFixEngineering` class doesn't return all .NET updates. The Windows Update API seems to list .NET updates, but I don't think it will return updates/patches/service packs you've applied manually.

Why are you so adamantly against "querying the registry"? Whatever API you settle on is probably going to do the same anyways

Comment: Just a rule around here. We can query the registry, and we do, but only as a last resort. I have to show due diligence before doing it. When the OS changes, a WMI class is more likely to continue working than an explicit registry query. When we change OS, we have to go through this again. Rules, rules, rules...

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to retrieve all updates (including .NET patches) with the [`IUpdateSearcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386515(v=vs.85).aspx) interface from the Windows Update Agent API:

```
$WUASession  = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$WUASearcher = $WUASession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Updates     = $WUASearcher.QueryHistory(0,$se.GetTotalHistoryCount())
```

Unfortunately, the items in the collection returned by `QueryHistory()` doesn't have a property with the KB #, only the title of the individual updates:

```
$dotNetUpdates = $Updates |Where-Object {$_.Title -match "Microsoft \.NET"}
```

Comment: The answer from Mathias only returns the WUSA patches and this is the same information that get-hotfix does. It does not include .NET patches. JT

Comment: So far this has not worked for me (does not include .NET patches). Have you had a chance to test this Mathias?

Comment: @JCSunday yes, WUA returned an additional 80 updates on my system (including .NET updates that were missing from `Win32_QuickFixEngineering`). As I wrote in the comment above, it still only includes patches installed with Windows Update, not those applied manually

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you!